# Is it possible to play non youtube videos on youtube player API?

Tags: android, youtube, media-player, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Simple question that i found no information about:

Is it possible to play non youtube videos on youtube player API? If no: Are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found quite good player https://github.com/lipangit/JieCaoVideoPlayer

it gets the job done for  me